# Request JPA with date and join

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

i have 2 tables : man and Entrance .

```
[man]

+------+-------+
| id   | name  |
+------+-------+
| 1    | man1  |
| 2    | man2  |
+------+-------+ 

[Entrance]

+------+--------------------------+-------+
| id   |         date             | idman |
+------+--------------------------+-------+
| 1    | 2008-10-29 14:56:59      |   1   |
| 2    | 2008-10-29 14:56:59      |   2   |
| 3    | 2008-10-29 17:56:59      |   2   |
| 4    | 2008-10-30 14:56:59      |   2   |
+------+--------------------------+-------+ 

[result]


+----------------+-------+
| count entrance | name  |
+----------------+-------+
| 1              | man1  |
| 2              | man2  |
+----------------+-------+
```

The man2 have than 2 because 2 entrance are on the same day.
Can you help me for pour Requette jpa make this?

Thanks you for your help .

Comment: Create 2 entities `Man` and `Entrance` and declare a ManyToOne relationship on `Entrance`'s side. Sorry but I don't want to provide some ready-to-copy-paste code. You have to try by yourself, show some code and the community will be happy to help you if you are stuck.

Comment: @MichelLammens To make sure I got ur question right, Given a date you want to get name of the person and number of times the person has entered on that day. Is it?

Comment: I tried this SELECT COUNT(e),m.name FROM man m join ENTRANCE e.entrance e . but then I would count only those who have different days if there are SEVERAL entry on the same day count only 1 entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is it what you're expecting?

```
SELECT max(t1.count_by_id), m.name, FROM (  
   SELECT id, cast(date as date) as cdate, count(*) as count_by_id
   FROM entrance    
   GROUP BY cdate, id) as t1 
INNER JOIN man m ON (t1.id = m.id) 
GROUP BY t1.id;
```

Comment: i have this error :Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7158] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Error encountered when building the @NamedQuery [SessionPersonne.findAllPremiereVisiteByPays] from entity class [class org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.queries.NamedQueryMetadata].
Internal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.parser.SubExpression cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.parser.IdentificationVariable